# Read field from BSON if exists

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Some of my bson documents will contain a certain field and some of them won't. I'd like to create some kind of conditional logic in my BSON deserialization method, so that I would be able to act upon the existence of such field. The coode I use for deserialization below:

```
public class AbstractStateSerializer : SerializerBase<AbstractState>, IBsonDocumentSerializer
{
    public override AbstractState Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        context.Reader.ReadStartDocument();
        context.Reader.ReadBsonType();
        context.Reader.SkipName();

        var representation = context.Reader.ReadInt32();

        // the below if statement and its body won't work, but this snippet illustrates my goal
        if (context.Reader.HasName("PreviousState")) {
            var prevState = context.Reader.ReadInt32();

            // do something with prevState
        }

        context.Reader.ReadEndDocument();

        var result = new AbstractState();

        // AbstractState object initialization, etc.

        return result;
    }

    // ...other methods required by the interface
}
```

How do I achieve something similar to the code starting with `if (context.Reader.HasName("PreviousState"))`? I'd like to avoid just blindly trying to read name, as I assume it will throw an exception if there's no name marker and if this method will be involved in reading many objects, it could result in many exceptions and that would hit my app's performance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no concept of `HasName` because you always need to read bytes one by one. Consider this workaround:

```
        public override AbstractState Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
        {
            context.Reader.ReadStartDocument();
            context.Reader.ReadBsonType();
            context.Reader.SkipName();

            var representation = context.Reader.ReadInt32();

            var bookmark = context.Reader.GetBookmark();
            var name = context.Reader.ReadName(Utf8NameDecoder.Instance);

            // the below if statement and its body won't work, but this snippet illustrates my goal
            if (name == "PreviousState")
            {
                var prevState = context.Reader.ReadInt32();

                // do something with prevState
            }
            else
            {
                context.Reader.ReturnToBookmark(bookmark);
            }

            context.Reader.ReadEndDocument();

            var result = new AbstractState();

            // AbstractState object initialization, etc.

            return result;
        }
```

NOTE: I didn't validate the whole logic.

Comment: Also, if you need to check whether your current node is `Type=Name` or not, you can check it via: context.Reader.State == BsonReaderState.Name